# Convert string vector to buffer

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a string vector which contains some number of strings greater than 500. I am using openssl functions that require buffers for encryption/decryption. Given that I am using string vectors and buffers in this manner, what is the best algorithm in terms of space and time to make this conversion. Each string can be assumed to be less than 200 chars.

Currently, I am extracting each entry in paths, concatenating the strings, calling the `.c_str()` method and using `strcpy` to extract from a function.

```
void copy(vector<string>& paths, unsigned char** plainTextBuffer, size_t& p_len){
int size = paths.size();
int i = 0;
string temp = "";
for(i=0; i<size; i++){
  temp+= paths[i];
  temp+= "\n";
}
p_len = temp.length();
(*plainTextBuffer) = malloc(p_len + 1);
strcpy((*plainTextBuffer), temp.c_str());
return;
}
```

Are there any built in tools to do this better and faster? (I have excluded error checking and casting from this snippet)

Edit:

I added the +1 to the malloc. I asked for a minimum complexity manner of getting from the initial conditions to the expected output. I am using malloc because I am using a simple buffer and it is faster than new.

Edit 2:

Thanks to some of the comments I am cutting out the middleman with some of the copying and have the following

```
void copy(vector<string>& paths, unsigned char** plainTextBuffer, size_t& p_len){
    int size = paths.size(), total = 0, i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
      total+= paths[i].size() + 1;
    }
    p_len = total;
    (*plainTextBuffer) = malloc(p_len + 1);
    (*plainTextBuffer)[0] = '\0';
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
      strcat((*plainTextBuffer), paths[i].c_str());
      strcat((*plainTextBuffer, "\n");
    }
    return;
}
```

Again I left out some casting. Is there a more efficient manner of getting the buffer data into the `plainTextBuffer`?

Comment: C != C++... C doesn't have vectors

Comment: Why? Just use the `vector`. It's like a string buffer with benefits.

Comment: Strings and vectors both a data accessor method http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/ You could use that directly without having to copy anything.

Comment: I am using openssl functions that require the use of buffers, not vectors or strings. Also, I included the c tag because the only c++ part of the code is the vector type.

Comment: @Dan Just to read, or to manipulate?

Comment: I need the data in a char * buffer for use in encryption.

Comment: You *do* remember that C++ (as well as C) strings require a special terminator character? If you don't allocate space for that character then`strcpy` will write it out of bounds. Also, if you're programming in C++, why use `malloc` instead of `new[]`?

Comment: If you need a `const char*` then you know that you can get it from a `std::string` object?

Comment: Joachim, I did not copy and paste this code so some of it is left out. I am using a different computer for this post. I need to take 1000s of strings and turn them into a buffer. Why am I getting downvoted?

Comment: Barry, the buffer will not be manipulated but is required for generating ciphertext using my current library and functions. I do not need to maintain the vector after this function.

Answer (score 5):

The fastest way to convert a `string` to a C-style string is to not do any conversions. So first, let's convert our `std::vector<std::string>` into one `std::string`:

```
std::vector<std::string> v = ...;
std::string output;
for (auto& s : v) {
    output += s;
    output += '\n';
}
```

And then you can pass that in:

```
void some_c_api(char*, size_t );
void some_const_c_api(const char*, size_t);

some_c_api(&output[0], output.size());
some_const_c_api(output.c_str(), output.size());
```

Comment: It is a `vector<string>` and I need the individual strings newline delimited in the buffer. Does dumping the data add a newline?

Comment: @Dan Just use `std::string` then, no need to use raw pointers.

Comment: So the best way is to just drop strcpy? I need to have the data extracted from the function in the buffer.

Comment: @Dan Yes, why would you create a whole new buffer for no reason?

Comment: This is the function declaration `void copy(vector<string>& paths, unsigned char** plainTextBuffer, size_t& p_len);` I need to extract the data in the buffer

Comment: @Dan Why? Why not call the function `std::string join(const std::vector<std::string>& paths)`? You haven't provided any reason to actually have a `char*`.

Comment: It eventually feeds into the following function: `static int encrypt(unsigned char* plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char* key, unsigned char* iv, unsigned char* ciphertext);` I am trying to get the plaintext value to feed into this function.

Answer (score 1):

Appending repeatedly into a string will result in the string repeatedly reallocating memory and shuffling its content into the new bigger space. A stringstream has a bigger creation cost, but it appends much faster than std::string, so instead of appending to a string in a loop, append to a stringstream:

```
stringstream temp;
for(size_t i=0; i<paths.size(); i++){
    temp << paths[i] << endl;
}
const std::string& tmp = temp.str();
```

Then just use tmp like you would have used your previous temp string. It is better to get a constant reference to temp.str() because it will not copy the content of the temporary created by str().

Comment: It eventually feeds into the following function: `static int encrypt(unsigned char* plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char* key, unsigned char* iv, unsigned char* ciphertext); ` I am trying to build the plaintext.

Comment: I meant that you could use tmp in your previous copy function. The char array returned by tmp.c_str() is a temporary that will die with the temp stream. My point was simply to replace the appending into a string in your copy function with appending into a stringstream. If you are 100% sure that encrypt does not modify plaintext and the call will not be made after stringstream temp falls out of scope, then you could even use it directly as an input, but safer will be to copy the char array somewhere.